# docker cp doesn't work for this mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker

Tried copying a directory and it doesn't seem to work.

Start a MySQL container.

```
docker cp mysql:/var/lib/mysql . 
cd mysql
ls
```

NOTHING.

Here's [the script](https://gist.github.com/joshuacalloway/51cc36160a009d3b01dc) to try it yourself.

---

extra info.

### On Ubuntu 14.04

```
jc@dev:~/work/jenkins/copy-sql/mysql$ docker -v
Docker version 1.2.0, build fa7b24f
```

Comment: Your script is short.  You should just include it inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/7461a52b43f06839a4d8723ae8841f4cb616b3d0/5.7/Dockerfile) for the image your container comes from, there is the [VOLUME](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume) instruction which tells Docker to leave the `/var/lib/mysql` directory **out of the container filesystem**.

The [docker cp](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#cp) can only access the container filesystem and thus won't see the files in mounted volumes.

If you need to backup your mysql data, I suggest you follow the instructions from the Docker userguide in section [Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes). You might also find the [discordianfish/docker-backup](https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-backup) docker image useful for that task.

---

Here's a little example to illustrate your case.

- given a simple Dockerfile with just a `VOLUME` instruction

`$ cat Dockerfile
FROM base
VOLUME /data`

- build an image named `test`

  ```
  $ docker build --force-rm -t test .
  ```
- run a container named `container_1` which will create two files, one being on the mounted volume

  ```
  $ docker run -d --name container_1 test bash -c 'echo foo > /data/foo.txt; echo bar > /tmp/bar.txt; while true; do sleep 1; done'
  ```
- make sure the container is running

`$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9e97aa18ac83        test:latest         "bash -c 'echo foo >   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            container_1`

- use the `docker cp` command to cp file `/tmp/bar.txt` and check its content

`$ docker cp container_1:/tmp/bar.txt .
$ cat bar.txt
bar`

- try the same with the file which is in the mounted volume (won't work)

`$ docker cp container_1:/data/foo.txt .
2014/09/27 00:03:43 Error response from daemon: Could not find the file /data/foo.txt in container container_1`

- now run a second container to print out the content of that file

`$ docker run --rm --volumes-from container_1 base cat /data/foo.txt
foo`

Comment: This was definitely the reason why.  Do you know why volume directories are outside of the container filesystem?   What's the reasoning for this?

Comment: There are multiple reasons for this, one is performances, the container filesystem is slow due to the layers it keeps, disk access to mounted volumes is more performant. Volumes are also useful if you want to share the data between multiple containers. It is also a good practice to make your containers immutable so you can delete and recreate them at will without worrying about their state or data. I advise to spend the necessary time to study Volumes in Docker so they become an asset for you instead of bringing confusion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass the `name` of your container to the `docker cp` command.  The [docs](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#cp) say it takes a container id.  Try grepping for "CONTAINER ID" in your script instead.

**EDIT**:

Since changing your script to grep for the Container ID didn't help, you should start by trying this manually (outside of your script).

The [docker cp](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#cp) command works.  The reason it's not working for you is either:

1. a permission thing
2. you're not formatting the command correctly, or
3. the directory doesn't exist in your container.

With a running container id of XXXX, try this (using your container id):

```
sudo docker cp XXXX:/var/lib/mysql .
```

If this doesn't work, and you don't get an error, I'd maybe suggest that that directory doesn't exist in your container.

**EDIT2:**

As I said, it's one of the 3 things above.
I get this when I run your script:

```
2014/09/26 16:10:18 lchown mysql: operation not permitted
```

Changing the last line of your script to prefix with `sudo` now gives no errors, but no directory either.

Run the container interactively:

```
docker run -t -i mysql /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
ls
```

...no files.

So your script is working fine.  **The directory is just empty (basically #3 above)**.

For reference, the mysql Dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/7461a52b43f06839a4d8723ae8841f4cb616b3d0/5.7/Dockerfile).

Comment: just tried the container id.  No dice.  Did you try it yourself?  script is in the url - gist

Comment: @jcalloway:  I didn't, but I don't have your container running either.  I've added some other suggestions.

Comment: you can try the script.  It's very simple.  Then you can try all the thing you are suggesting.   I have tried all the thing you listed here and they did not work.  But I could have overlooked something

Comment: @jcalloway: ran it, results added to answer

Comment: thanks for taking a look.  I think Thomas has the answer below, but I need to try it now